# Javascript looping behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, theory

The `alltones` array contains all the possible notes in music scale.

```
var alltones = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" ];
```

I want to take the user's input of a tone, and then construct a list that contains certain elements of the array.

Say I start at `alltones[5]` or `"F"`, and want to take every second element of the array from that point and put it into my list, until I get back around to `"F"`. The array is more like a circle than straight list. I'm a little unsure of how the array operates once the loop reaches the last element.

Do I approach the problem by generating a new array, based on the users input. Or is there a way that JavaScript knows to loop back to the start of an array once it reaches the end such that it treats the array like a circle?

An example:
User input = F 
The output that I am seeking is to count (every two items) from F until we get back around the array to F
so the desired output would be => F G A B C# D#

Comment: Maybe modulo indexing is what you would want - something like `alltones[x % alltones.length]`

Comment: Sounds like you can create a new array using slice and array.indexOf and concat before taking the notes

Comment: Can you show us a few sample runs (the input, and expected output) that you're seeking? That is needed to determine what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an [existing Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods) to do what you want, but one is easily defined using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
// move i elements from the start of the array to the end of the array
Array.prototype.lcycle = function(i) {
  var xs = this.slice(0,i);
  var ys = this.slice(i);
  return ys.concat(xs)
};
// move i elements from the end of the array to the start of the array
Array.prototype.rcycle = function(i) {
  var xs = this.slice(0,-i);
  var ys = this.slice(-i);
  return ys.concat(xs);
};
```

And then you can use `lcycle` and `rcycle`  as normal array methods:

```
>>> alltones.lcycle(3)
[ "D#" , "E" , "F" , "F#" , "G" , "G#" , "A" , "A#" , "B" , "C" , "C#" , "D" ]
>>> alltones.rcycle(4)
[ "G#" , "A" , "A#" , "B" , "C" , "C#" , "D" , "D#" , "E" , "F" , "F#" , "G" ]
```

Note that both of these methods return a new array.  If you wanted to mutate the original array, you could define similar methods using [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
// move i elements from the start of the array to the end of the array, mutating the original array
Array.prototype.lcycle_m = function(i) {
  var args = this.splice(0,i);
  args.unshift(0);
  args.unshift(this.length);
  this.splice.apply(this, args);
};
// move i elements from the end of the array to the start of the array, mutating the original array
Array.prototype.rcycle_m = function(i) {
  var args = this.splice(-i);
  args.unshift(0);
  args.unshift(0);
  this.splice.apply(this, args);
};
```

And again, you can can use `lcycle_m` and `rcycle_m` as normal array methods:

```
>>> alltones.lcycle_m(3)
>>> alltones
[ "D#" , "E" , "F" , "F#" , "G" , "G#" , "A" , "A#" , "B" , "C" , "C#" , "D" ]
>>> alltones.rcycle_m(3)
>>> alltones
[ "C" , "C#" , "D" , "D#" , "E" , "F" , "F#" , "G" , "G#" , "A" , "A#" , "B" ]
```

Comment: Old post...but this is a very good answer. I never considered extending the array prototype in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two loops, as JS has no built in support for circles.

```
for (var i = users_input; i < alltones.length; i += 1) {
  ... use alltones[i] for calc
}
for (var i = 0; i < users_input; i += 1) {
  ... use alltones[i] for calc
}
```

or something along that line.
There really is no need for creating a new array.

Comment: That sounds overly complicated. Imagine a very complex loop body

Comment: or one loop `for (var i = 0; i < alltones.length; i ++) { var j = (i + users_input) % alltones.length; /* use alltones[j] for calc */ }`

Comment: for the complex loop body you can move the login into a function, and call with an argument. the one-loop sounds good, I'll copy that into my toolbox

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function getNotes(index) {
  var list = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" ];
  return list.splice(index).concat(list).filter(function(note, i) {
    return i % 2 == 0;
  });
}
getNotes(3); // ["D#", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#"]
```

What this does is reorganize the array first so that the selected index is shifted to the beginning and everything before that is moved to the end, and then filters out every other note. If you'd rather have the `getNotes` function consume a string, you can use the `indexOf` method. `indexOf` and `filter` (used above) are part of ECMAScript 5 so you may need polyfills depending on what browsers you plan on supporting.

Here's a [Fiddle with some examples](http://jsfiddle.net/SQNan/1/).

Comment: +1 neat solution, but I'm surprised you didn't put the second `return` on the same line ;)

Comment: Just personal preference, I suppose. I find it more readable; I always add a newline and indent for a function body.

Comment: My comment was an apparently failed attempt of irony ;)

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Never would have though of that. Thanks for the fiddle example too!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to loop back to the start of an array once it reaches the end:

`arr[index%arr.length]`, if `index` > `arr.length`, it will "loop" to the start.

this tech is efficient, and works for almost every language.

```
var alltones = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" ];

function generateMusic(startIndex) {
    var i = 0, music = [],
        tonesCount = alltones.length

    do { 
        music.push(alltones[(startIndex+i)%tonesCount]); 
    } while ((i+=2) < tonesCount);

    return music;
}
```

Result:

```
console.log(generateMusic(3)); //["D#", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#"]
console.log(generateMusic(5)); //["F", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#"]
```

Answer (score 0):

doing it in two loops one for array members starting after the initial point and another from the beginning is a better way; the key here is to start from the beginning depending where we left off at the end of the array.

you can create a generic function like

```
  var alltones = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" ];

  function build_tones(arr, start, jump_by){

  var new_list = [];

           //finish first iteration and get the last index so that we can offset accordingly from the beginning
             var get_last = (function(){
               var last;
              for(i = start; i <= arr.length; i+=jump_by){
                new_list.push(arr[i]);
                last = i;
                }
              return last;
              })();

     //do the second iteration by picking up from the index left and continue from first

    for(i = 0 + arr.length%get_last; i < start; i+=jump_by){
    new_list.push(arr[i]);
    }

    return new_list;

  }

 var result = build_tones(alltones, 5, 2);
 console.log(result);
```